# why my asio4all is not working?

Tags: sound, fl-studio

I've been working on a project for while but today when I opened it I found out there's no sound coming out of the Fl Studio and also there's a exclamation point on asio4all icon on the taskbar. I really don't know the problem, if someone could tell me what is wrong with it i would really appreciate the help.[image]

Comment: Have you tried turning... uninstalling and reinstalling the ASIO drivers? It's a pretty common problem with FL Studio (I encountered it at least 2 times in the good olde days). Modern versions of FL Studio come with their own rendition of the ASIO driver, why don't you try to change the settings to use them?

Comment: @Pyromonk I just reinstalled the ASIO driver but it didn't make a difference. and i also tried the FL studio Asio but it's not working either. But you know when I open a new project there's no problem but with this current project ASIO driver is not working 

Comment: Have you tried checking CPU load and closing down everything (like browsers and Steam) besides FL? What about the master channel? Does it receive input and produce output? What about increasing ASIO buffer size? [This](https://www.image-line.com/support/flstudio_online_manual/html/envsettings_asio4all.htm) and [that](https://www.reddit.com/r/FL_Studio/comments/68dhp9/asio4all_trolling_meagain/) might help solve the issue. You could also try uploading the project somewhere, so that I can take a look at it on my system (if you feel that option is safe).

Comment: @Pyromonk this the project : https://workupload.com/file/6ZqpnccQ

Comment: I've downloaded the archive, so you can take it down if you don't want anyone else to have access to it.

Comment: [Everything is fine in Producer Edition 20.6](https://www.dropbox.com/s/etn5huuix7go9xc/taylor_2.flp?dl=0). Can you test the project with that new .flp file and see if it works? It might be a simple matter of "saving as new" or upgrading FL Studio to the most recent version.

Comment: @Pyromonk your Fl Studio version is different of mine. but if I upgrade my FL Studio then i wouldn't be able to open my other projects. when I opened new flp with my current version it was exactly like a new project. all in blank ... but ASIO was ok .  this is the pop-up message when i opened the flp : https://pasteboard.co/IZyvpE9.png

Comment: Ok, [I've exported the project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fwev4csnurqiydc/AACnHeCAblAV49f1HAJkcYO0a?dl=0) in exactly the same version of FL Studio that you have. Let me know if it works now.